# listbox don't exist C#

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public static List<string> GetAllFilesFromFolder(string root, bool searchSubfolders)
{
    Queue<string> folders = new Queue<string>();
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    folders.Enqueue(root);
    while (folders.Count != 0)
    {
        string currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();
        try
        {
            string[] filesInCurrent = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentFolder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            files.AddRange(filesInCurrent);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
        try
        {
            if (searchSubfolders)
            {
                string[] foldersInCurrent = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentFolder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string _current in foldersInCurrent)
                {
                    folders.Enqueue(_current);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

The code list all files to `List<string>` but I need to see it in `listbox.items`, I tried

```
foreach(string foo in files)
    listbox1.items.add(foo)
```

The problem is it doesn't recognize the `listbox1` and keep saying that it doesn't exist. How can I do it? It is a Windows Forms application.

Comment: So where is your `listbox1` defined? Maybe in another class?

Comment: listBox1 is part of windows form1 application

Comment: code you have written above may not be under your `yourform.cs` file (i.e. under the code section of the respective form) or your `listbox1` has a different name (such as `listBox1`); case matters in the names.